# How to add Objects to an Array and print it?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm trying to make a deck class in which a person can add objects from a main class. Let's say in my sub class, I have a method called `public void add(Object n)`
then in my main class I add deck `objects` like "Spades","Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs" etc.
 It should print out the deck. 
This is my code for my method class. I haven't made the method yet but in the deck2 would equal n. 
So when someone does `add.("Spades")` it will add that to deck 2.

```
 Object [] deck=new Object[52];
        Object [] Suits=new Object[4];
        Object [] Ranks=new Object[17];
        Object deck2[]={"Spades","Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","King","Queen","Ace"};
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            Suits[i]=deck2[i];

        }
            for(int i=4;i<Ranks.length;i++){
                Ranks[i]=deck2[i];
            System.out.println(Ranks[i]);
        }

            for(int i=0;i<deck.length;i++){
                deck[i]=Ranks[i%13]+" "+"of "+Suits[i/13];
            System.out.println(deck[i]);

}}}
```

It should give the same output as this. This is split up but in the method i'm trying to create. I can only have one object.

```
Object [] deck2=new Object [52];
        Object[] deck=new Object [52];

        Object suits[]={"Spades","Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs"};
        Object rank[]={"2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","King","Queen","Ace"};
        System.out.println("               Normal Deck");
        for(int i=0;i<deck.length;i++){
            deck[i]=rank[i%13]+" "+"of "+suits[i/13];
            deck2[i]=deck[i];
            System.out.println(deck[i]+",");}
```

Comment: Did you not learn anything from the effort that I gave you yesterday?  Why are you using Object arrays?

Comment: Because for one of the assignment it asks you for Object array.

Comment: So first i would recommend using an `ArrayList` instead of an array. Also, when someone refers to an array of objects, you need to make a new class and make an array of that class. After all, Java is OOP. If you were to treat it like this, you could then have methods inside of your class that handle all the issues you are having here.

Answer (score 0):

All right, there is a difference between array of objects and array of Objects.
"Object" is the superclass of all java objects.
Most probably your assignment is referring to object not the "Object" class.
So first create a class called Card.

```
class Card
{
  private String rank;
  private String suit;

  public Card(String suit, String rank)
  {
    this.suit = suit;
    this.rank = rank;
  }

  //Add getter methods

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return ("Suit :" + suit + " and Rank :" + rank);
  }
}
```

now in your main method
create an ArrayList of card object.
Like this

```
ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
```

Create card objects and add them to the list.
eg

```
cards.add(new Card("Heart", "10"));
cards.add(new Card("Spades", "King"));
```

After populating you ArrayList do this print all the card objects.

```
for(Card card: cards)
{
  System.out.println(card.toString());
}
```